# Is the space of continuous and bijective functions $f\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ complete?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $X$ be the space of continuous and bijective functions $f$, such that
>   $$ f\colon [0,1] \to [0,1] \quad , \quad f(0)=0 \quad , \quad f(1)=1 \, .$$
>   Is $X$ complete (under the supremum norm  $ \|.\|_\infty$ )?

I can show that if instead of bijectivity we only require surjectivity then it is complete, but I have not been able to do so if we also require injectivity ( I'm not sure if it is still complete).

Comment: @Winther, does your sequence converge uniformly?

Comment: @peter Nope. $xe^{-n(1-x)}$ only converges uniformly on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ so its not a good example here. I'll remove it:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a sequence of continuous bijections can converge uniformly to a function that isn't one-to-one. Let $f_n$ be the piecewise linear function obtained by linear interpolation between the points $(0,0), (\frac14,\frac12-\frac1n),(\frac34,\frac12+\frac1n),(1,1)$. For each $n\geq3$, this is a bijection, but the uniform limit is constant on the interval from $\frac14$ to $\frac34$.